# Change default colour used in Boadilla

Tags: beamer, color

I am making a beamer presentation using Boadilla style. However, I would like to change the default blue colour. Is there a quick fix for this, please? Thank you!

The following is my code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[TITLE]{TITLE}

\subtitle{SUB TITLE}

\author{AUTHOR}
\institute[SCHOOL]{SCHOOL COLLEGE UNIVERSITY}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Huge The End\\
\Huge Thank You!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `\usecolortheme{crane}` shows a 'nice' Goldenrod - like color theme.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Cool. Thank you. Is there a list of all possible color.

Comment: Check out the [`beamer` theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) which shows different themes under various colour themes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very simple way to specify the color is with `\usecolortheme[⟨options⟩]{structure}` (see Sec. 17.1 of the beamer documentation). The color can be named or specified using RGB, cmyk, etc. This will change the color of the main elements, but not everything.

For example, if you want most elements some shade of purple, you can do the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme[named=purple]{structure}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[TITLE]{TITLE}
\subtitle{SUB TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\institute[SCHOOL]{SCHOOL COLLEGE UNIVERSITY}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Block}
Standard beamer block
\end{block}
\begin{alertblock}{Block}
Alert block
\end{alertblock}
\begin{exampleblock}{Block}
Example block
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will change the normally blue elements to whatever you define, but leave others (such as `exampleblock` and `alertblock`) untouched.

[image]

If you want to be much more specific with your definitions, you can also set the color of any element in the frame using `\setbeamercolor`

Answer (score 9):

The `Boadilla` theme loads three different colour themes, in this order:

1. [`default`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemedefault.sty);
2. [`dolphin`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemedolphin.sty); and
3. [`rose`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemerose.sty)

Looking at these three colour themes, they all rely on what is set by the `default` colour theme (apart from some fixed choices like `black` and `white`). And, the `defaut` colour theme actually sets all its colours based on a single colour: `beamer@blendedblue` that has the following definition:

```
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
```

A quick fix then, while still maintaining the same layout and structural flavour, would be to redefine `beamer@blendedblue` to suit your needs. For example,

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[TITLE]{TITLE}

\subtitle{SUB TITLE}

\author{AUTHOR}
\institute[SCHOOL]{SCHOOL COLLEGE UNIVERSITY}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{orange!70!red}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Above I've changed the default blue colour to be 70% orange and 30% red. Let's call it grapefruit.

Answer (score 5):

This uses the `crane` theme and in addition some changes to it using `\setbeamercolor*` macro with the relevant 'beamer-color-category' such as `titlelike` or `block title`.

Each of those categories has a foreground (fg) and a background (bg) specifier, to be given as 2nd argument to `\setbeamercolor`.

The number of `beamer-color-categories` is too large to list them here. I refer to the 
[Beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)

```
\documentclass[xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usecolortheme{crane}

\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{bg=Coral3,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{title page}{bg=Coral3,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=Aquamarine3}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[TITLE]{TITLE}

\subtitle{SUB TITLE}

\author{AUTHOR}
\institute[SCHOOL]{SCHOOL COLLEGE UNIVERSITY}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{block}{Hello}
Some text
\end{block}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Huge The End\\
\Huge Thank You!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition, please have a look on

[Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix)